# BufferedInputStream available() eating CPU

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, bufferedinputstream

I'm reading messages from a socket (trough a TCP protocol), but I note that the CPU spend a lot of time to call the method   available() of my BufferedInputStream. This is my code:

```
    @Override
public void run()
{

    Socket socket;
    Scanner scanner;
    BufferedInputStream buffer = null;

    try
    {
        socket = new Socket(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT);

        System.out.println("Connection Completed");

        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        buffer = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

        StringBuilder readCharacter;

        while (true)
        {

            readCharacter = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {

                while (buffer.available() > 0)
                {
                    readCharacter.append((char) buffer.read());
                }

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                buffer.close();
            }

            String array[] = separe(new String(readCharacter));
         ... //parsing the message
```

I've also tried to use int `read=buffer.read()` and check `if (read!=-1)` instead of using the available function, but in this case I'm not able to recognize the end of the message...in my StringBuilder 'readCharacter' I have more than one message, one after the other..and it cause the fail of my parsing process...

Instead using the `available()` check, into the `readCharacter` I have only one message at a time..and the parsing works...

Can you help me to understand why, and how avoid the eating of CPU?

Comment: Well then, try parsing inside the while loop with .read() method.

Comment: Hi..you mean keeping the available() check or using the read()!=-1 ?? However I've tried both approaches but they don't work

Comment: There is a common misconception that you can imply when a message starts and end by the pauses between data. You can't send messages of a byte stream, only bytes. You can only determine when a message starts and end by reading the contents.

Comment: Can you explain more about that??You say I have to use another mechanism to handle the messages??

Answer (score 3):

This loop:

```
while (buffer.available() > 0)
  {
  readCharacter.append((char) buffer.read());
  }
```

can be replaced with simple:

```
readCharacter.append((char) buffer.read());
```

Instead of calling non-blocking `available()` over and over again (which consumes a lot of CPU) just call `read()` which will block not consuming CPU until something is available. Looks like this is what you want to achieve with less code and complexity.

Comment: The problem is that if I delete the while, I read a character and I pass only a single character to my parser..

Comment: @marco: Now I see that your code is generally broken (also see Peter Lawreys' comment to your question). You cannot assume that your message is done just because there are no more bytes to read from the stream (think about network or I/O contention). But if you really want to go this path, first call blocking `read()` and then call `available()` once to see how many bytes you can further read without blocking.

Comment: If you read `42` and for next 10 seconds nothing arrived from the network, does this mean this is your complete input? Or maybe the network is saturated and the complete input is `425 123\n`? I don't know what are you actually writing, but probably your input is *line-* or *token-oriented*. Maybe your fields are separated by something? Maybe you up-front that you need to read some amount of data?

Comment: Yes my input is token oriented..In practice I send serialized messages (c++ text archive using the boost library), which are essentially sequence of characters...They are separated by a white space, I parse the message with a Java Scanner, I take each character and I assign the value to the field of my class..

Answer (score 1):

The `available()` itself does not eat CPU. What does it is your loop:

```
while (buffer.available() > 0) {
    readCharacter.append((char) buffer.read());
}
```

While bytes are unavailable you are actually calling `available()` multiple times (probably thousands of times). Since `read()` method of streams is blocking you do not have to call `available()` at all. The following code does the same but does not eat CPU.

```
String line = null;
while ((line = buffer.read()) != null) {
    readCharacter.append(line);
}
```

Comment: Your example does not compile since `InputStream.read()` has a return type of `int` and not `String`. You probably mean `BufferedReader.readLine()` method.

Comment: surely I mean `BufferedReader`. Probably variable name `buffer` confused me. Anyway this is not the issue. The issue where and when `available()` should be used.